# How to query prisma for a custom condition in NestJS

Tags: nestjs, prisma

I have this query

```
const jobs = await this.prisma.job.findMany({
      skip,
      take: limit,
      where: {
        userId,
        customConditionHere <=====,
      },
      select: {
        name: true,
        status: true,
        date: true,
        category: true,
        id: true,
        jobOffers: true,
      },
    });
```

I need a way to check whether or not the `location` field of my `job` model fulfils certain condition that I would specify in an async function (I need to send location to google api to check its coordinates). For example something like

```
where:{
location: await customCondition(job)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just fetch all necessary data before running the query

```js
const location = await customCondition(job);

const jobs = await this.prisma.job.findMany({
      skip,
      take: limit,
      where: {
        userId,
        location,
      },
      select: {
        name: true,
        status: true,
        date: true,
        category: true,
        id: true,
        jobOffers: true,
      },
});
```

Comment: Thats not what I am trying to do. I need function to be passed to location or whatever so that it can take the location as an argument, calculate whether or not that location fulfils conditions and return boolean or something that will make prisma recognize that I want it taken into the query. I've read docs and didn't find anything useful

Comment: I'm not aware of anything similar supported by Prisma. I suggest trying to get all necessary constraints before running the query and applying them in the where statement dynamically with OR. https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/filtering-and-sorting#filter-conditions-and-operators